# How to handle many arguments options in a complex C code

Tags: c

I have to write a program in C which has several options on command line when it starts. I was wondering how to handle with a big amount of possible options. I mean, I have already found how to parse them with argp or getopt.
Now I have to deal with them. For example, there's the classic option "--verbose | -v". How do I make my program "verbose"? Do I have to write every time something like "if(verboseFlag) printf("...");"? I think that this approach could be dirty when having a lot of arguments. So, what are the possible approaches?

Comment: `Do I have to write every time something like` - yes. Or wrap that in a function, ex. `void myprintf(const char *fmt, ...) { if (verboseFlag) { ... vprintf(fmt, va); ..; } }` or a macro `#define myprintf(...) do{if(verboseFlat) { printf(__VA_ARGS__); }}while(0)`. That's exactly how it works.  ex. [grep out_quiet](https://github.com/mfragkoulis/grep/blob/master/src/grep.c#L1389).

Comment: @KamilCuk depends on what he wants to do.  If he generates a big data structure and in function of the options passed to `main` he decides if he sends the data structure either to debug or to print it in other way or to send it toward the next processing level, it is easier to do with interfaces, as I specified.  I am not sure what he wants to do.  Maybe he details .

Comment: Sometimes you just have to go the long route and write a full option parser like I just did in Looking Glass, see here for an example: https://github.com/gnif/LookingGlass/blob/master/common/src/option.c

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of possibilities. Here is one. You can use a structure that defines your interface

```
typedef struct {
  void* method1(void);
  void* method2(void);
  void* method3(void);
} interface;
```

In function of your options that you pass from command line to main() you initialize this interface with different methods

```
  interface *i;
  switch (option) {
  case VERBOSE: i->method1=verbose_m1; i->method2=verbose_m2; ...a.s.o.
  break;
  case DEBUG: i->method1=debug_m1; i->method2=debug_m2; ...a.s.o.
  break;
  default: i->method1=m1; i->method2=m2; i->method3=m3;
  }
```

and you write a single code in which you call `i->method1` .

There are more elegant methods for this, to use uml or type classes , etc.  These elegant methods will generate low level code and on your side you define in a simple language the interface, etc.  To see how such a language looks like you can look over [asdl](http://asdl.sourceforge.net/), which is a very simple language in this spirit.